# AWS ELB - All application versions have not reached a "Processed" state. Unable to continue with deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm unable to deploy code on Elastic Beanstalk CLI for some odd reason.  I'm using CodeCommit, and after a long while, it errors out and gives me the following:

```
Starting environment deployment via CodeCommit
--- Waiting for Application Versions to be pre-processed ---
ERROR: All application versions have not reached a "Processed" state. Unable to continue with deployment.
```

Then it just ends.  I'm unable to use the commands `eb create` nor `eb deploy`.  I'm not sure what the error means by not reaching a "Processed" state... At the time of this writing, I only have one application and one environment, and it's current status is "OK" (green), as it's our main website and it's running fine.  I just want to do a code update to it, but I'm unable to.

Now the only way I can deploy it is via the GUI, by going into the Application Versions page and clicking on Deploy.  But I used to be able to do it fine on the EB CLI.

I've tried to do a search for that specific error but have yielded nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around, I finally figured out what went wrong.  I used this post as a hint: [What does ElasticBeanstalk error "Application version is unusable and cannot be used with an environment" mean?](https://serverfault.com/questions/771322/what-does-elasticbeanstalk-error-application-version-is-unusable-and-cannot-be)

And ran the command `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions` which told me that one of my Application Versions had a `"FAILED"` status.  I deleted all the `FAILED` ones, and tried again, then got the same error message.  I suspected that perhaps my last change triggered the `FAILED` status, so I saw on AWS that there are two reasons:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/events.common.appversionfailure.html

I realized that my latest code update ballooned the code up to 313MB, so I deleted some portions that I didn't need (even though it didn't exceed 512MB), that seemed to solve the issue.